# python tkinter exec issue

Tags: python, tkinter, exec

total 60 tkinter entries named e0,e1....e59,60 Labels l0,l1....l59. the function works fine like this.
**Version_one:**

```
def CreateCharacter():
    root.destroy()
    chcreation = tk.Tk()
    global e0, e1,..... e59
    l0 = tk.Label(chcreation, text=char[0],  fg='black')
    l0.grid(row=0, column=0)
    e0 = tk.Entry(chcreation, fg='black')
    e0.grid(row=1, column=0)
    ...........
    e59 = tk.Entry(chcreation, fg='black')
    e59.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

but if I switch to the "exec" method like below the other function cannot pick up the **global** variables e0 e1....e59 to collect the inputs.
**Version_two:**

```
def CreateCharacter():
    root.destroy()
    chcreation = tk.Tk()
    chcreation.title('create new character')
    chcreation.geometry('1100x500+50+100')
    global e0, e1, ..... e59  
    for i in range(60):
        ro = (i // 11) * 2
        col = i % 11
        exec("l%s=tk.Label(chcreation,text=char[%d])" % (i,i))#char is a name list
        exec("l%s.grid(row=ro,column=col, padx=5, pady=2)" % i)
        exec("e%s=tk.Entry(chcreation, fg='black',width=12)" % i)
        exec("e%s.grid(row=ro+1,column=col, padx=5, pady=2)" % i)
```

the labels and entries displayed good in the 'chcreation' window,but when other function called this one, error is "NameError: name 'e0' is not defined". But I defined them globally and in Version_one version they work ok . Please advice.

the calling function is like this:

```
def Charater_creating(en):
    crole = []
    for i in range(60):
        exec("crole.append(e%s.get())"%i)
    raw_data = pd.DataFrame(crole, index=mul_index)
    raw_data.to_csv('char.csv',header=False,mode='a')
    for i in range(60):
        exec("e%s.delete(0,'end')"%i)
```

the whole code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

array_index = [['Basic', 'Basic' ],['Name', 'Nickname']]
char = array_index[1]
mul_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(array_index)
role = pd.DataFrame([], index=mul_index)


def CreateCharacter():
    root.destroy()
    chcreation = tk.Tk()
    chcreation.geometry('1200x500+50+100')
    global e0, e1

    #error block
    for i in char:
        t = char.index(i)
        ro = (t // 11) * 2
        col = t % 11
        exec("l%s=tk.Label(chcreation,text=char[%d])" % (t, t))
        exec("l%s.grid(row=ro,column=col, padx=5, pady=2)" % t)
        exec("e%s=tk.Entry(chcreation, fg='black',width=12)" % t)
        exec("e%s.grid(row=ro+1,column=col, padx=5, pady=2)" % t)

    #below is the working block
    # l0 = tk.Label(chcreation, text=char[0], font=('Arial', 12), fg='black')
    # l0['height'] = 2
    # l0['width'] = 8
    # l0.grid(row=0, column=0)
    # e0 = tk.Entry(chcreation, font=('Arial', 10), fg='black')
    # e0['width'] = 8
    # e0.grid(row=1, column=0)
    # l1 = tk.Label(chcreation, text=char[1], font=('Arial', 12), fg='black')
    # l1['height'] = 2
    # l1['width'] = 8
    # l1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    # e1 = tk.Entry(chcreation, font=('Arial', 10), fg='black')
    # e1['width'] = 8
    # e1.grid(row=1, column=1)


    creat_button = tk.Button(chcreation, text='OK', font=('Arial', 8), fg='black')
    creat_button['width'] = 8
    creat_button['height'] = 2
    creat_button.grid(row=11, column=5)
    creat_button.bind('<Button-1>', Charater_creating)


def Charater_creating(en):
    crole = [e0.get(), e1.get()]
    raw_data = pd.DataFrame(crole, index=mul_index)
    raw_data.to_csv('character_data11.csv', header=False, mode='a')
    e0.delete(0, 'end')
    e1.delete(0, 'end')


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('900x400+200+50')
c_cbutn = tk.Button(root, text='new', font=('Arial', 20), fg='red', command=CreateCharacter)
c_cbutn['height'] = 2
c_cbutn['width'] = 15
c_cbutn.grid(row=3, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So, what is the real code in the `global` line?

Comment: global e0, e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10, e11, e12, e13, e14, e15, e16, e17, e18, e19, e20, e21, e22, e23, e24, e25, e26, e27, e28, e29, e30
   e31, e32, e33, e34, e35, e36, e37, e38, e39, e40, e41, e42, e43, e44, e45, e46, e47, e48, e49, e50, e51, e52, e53, e54, e55, e56, e57, e58, e59

Comment: I just deleted it.not make any confusion.

Comment: What if there is only one entry?

Comment: Hmmm, not getting this to work. Can you post working code, that we can paste into IDLE and run, which produces this problem. Also, make it with only one label and entry to keep it short...

Comment: Why are you making this so complicated instead of using dictionaries or lists?

Comment: Can you please post code which produces this problem. Not just the functions you have posted, but a functioning program including imports and mainloop() statements; something that we can paste directly into IDLE and run.

Comment: @Goyo the list approach is good， I just cannot figure out why the exec is not working.

Comment: Post a [mcve] and probably somebody will be able to tell you exacty why it doesn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: @Goyo ,  As you advised ,I post all the code.

Comment: @figbeam, working code posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be the problem; In the code with `exec` you create entrys with:

```
exec("e%s_Entry=tk.Entry(chcreation, fg='black',width=12)" % i)
```

which assigns the names: `e0_Entry, e1_Entry, ... etc.` to the widgets. So the names `e0, e1, ... etc.` will not be defined.

**Additional thoughts**

I found the problem but I don't know why it is. Consider the functions below:

```
def go_a():
    global a
    a = 25
    print(a)

go_a() # This works just fine


def go_b():
    global b
    exec("b = 25")
    print(b)    

go_b() # Generates NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

For some reason the function which uses the `exec` function does not set the name "b" in the global namespace unless it already exists there. See below:

```
b = 9   # Setting the name "b"
go_b()  # As if by magic, this now works
```

So this is a problem with `exec` and scope but I don't really understand why.

My suggestion is to store the entries in a list or dict instead, as Bryan suggests.

Comment: Added investigation into `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `exec` to create variables. It makes the code nearly impossible to understand and maintain.

If you want to create a large number of widgets (or objects of any type), store them in a list or dictionary.

```
widgets = []
for i in range(60):
    ro = (i // 11) * 2
    col = i % 11
    widget = tk.Label(chcreation,text=i)
    widgets.append(widget)
```

You can now reference each label with something like `widgets[0]`, `widgets[1]`, etc. This works well if your index is an integer and starts at zero.

-or-

```
widgets = {}
...
widgets[i] = widget
```

The above works better when your index is not an integer. As with the list, you still reference widgets the same way (eg: `widgets[0]`, etc)

Comment: the list approach is good， I just cannot figure out why the exec is not working.